# Firefoxのスニペットエディタ

Tags: html, firefox

Firefoxにて、Safari標準の「スニペットエディタ」のように
ファイルにHTMLコードを保存すること無く、入力したHTMLコードをすぐにレンダリングできる方法は無いでしょうか。
アドオンでも構いません。

よろしくお願いします。